# vba transforming formula in value

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

i have this routine:

```
Sub toevoegen()

  With Worksheets(SheetSchaduwblad)

    aantalrijen = .Range("A1", .Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Cells.Count

    .Range("S2:S" & aantalrijen) = "=IF(RC[-13]>0,""ja"",if(RC[-14]>0,""ja"",""nee""))"
    .Range("T2:T" & aantalrijen) = "=IF(RC[-11]>0,""ja"",if(RC[-12]>0,""ja"",""nee""))"
    .Range("U2:U" & aantalrijen) = "=IF(RC[-9]>0,""ja"",if(RC[-10]>0,""ja"",""nee""))"
    .Range("V2:V" & aantalrijen) = "=IF(RC[-7]>0,""ja"",if(RC[-8]>0,""ja"",""nee""))"
    .Range("W2:W" & aantalrijen) = "=IF(RC[-6]=""MERK"",""ja"",""nee"")"
    .Range("X2:x" & aantalrijen) = "=IF(RC[-6]=""UPC/EAN Code"",""ja"",""nee"")"

    End With
End Sub
```

I am wondering if and how I can directly change the formula's into hard values using VBA.

I tried to add this routine:

```
 .Range ("S2:X" & aantalrijen)
        .Value = .Value
```

which makes this the complete routine:

```
Sub toevoegen()

  With Worksheets(SheetSchaduwblad)

    aantalrijen = .Range("A1", .Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Cells.Count

    .Range("S2:S" & aantalrijen) = "=IF(RC[-13]>0,""ja"",if(RC[-14]>0,""ja"",""nee""))"
    .Range("T2:T" & aantalrijen) = "=IF(RC[-11]>0,""ja"",if(RC[-12]>0,""ja"",""nee""))"
    .Range("U2:U" & aantalrijen) = "=IF(RC[-9]>0,""ja"",if(RC[-10]>0,""ja"",""nee""))"
    .Range("V2:V" & aantalrijen) = "=IF(RC[-7]>0,""ja"",if(RC[-8]>0,""ja"",""nee""))"
    .Range("W2:W" & aantalrijen) = "=IF(RC[-6]=""MERK"",""ja"",""nee"")"
    .Range("X2:x" & aantalrijen) = "=IF(RC[-6]=""UPC/EAN Code"",""ja"",""nee"")"

    .Range ("S2:X" & aantalrijen)
        .Value = .Value
     End With
End Sub
```

but when executed, it showed me an error warning: `error 438: this property or method is not supported by this object`

I found this routine on internet:

```
Sub Range_Example_1()
    With Range("A5:D100")
        .Cells.Copy
        .Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        .Cells(1).Select
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

I am wondering if I need this copy/paste as value or if I can make the formula write values directly.

Comment: What error warning? You should be able to do that w/o copy/paste.

Comment: error 438: this property or method is not supported by this object (do not know if that is the english version, I have the dutch office version so I translated it myself)

Comment: 1) What is the value of `aantalrijen`? 2) Where is `SheetSchaduwblad` defined (though assume that is not the problem if the rest of your code works).

Comment: SheetsSchaduwblad is defined at the top of the module after the option explicit declaration. The value of aantalrijen I will check after the code running now is finished.

Comment: In the line before `.Value=.Value` have you added another With in front of the Ranges? You need `With .Range ("S2:X" & aantalrijen)` and then another End With afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the error from this line:

```
.Range ("S2:X" & aantalrijen)
    .Value = .Value
```

It is within the `With` statement, so the `.Value` after the `=` refers to `Worksheets(SheetSchaduwblad).Value`. A worksheet does not have a value though, so if you want the value without the formula in the cell you would need to refer to the cell again.

```
.Range("S2:X" & aantalrijen).Value = .Range("S2:X" & aantalrijen).Value
```

Should do the trick, you can avoid using `Range` twice using a nested `With`

```
With .Range("S2:X" & aantalrijen)
.Value = .Value
End With
```

Comment: after changing the script to what you suggested and changing .value = .text to .value = .value the script works fine.

Comment: Yes, also realized that after testing. .text only works for single cells, so you would need to loop through the range. .value works with range, so that's easier to write.